# convergence of $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sin^2(\frac 1 k)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> convergence of $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sin^2(\frac 1 k)$

How can I do this? Should I use the Ratio Test (I tried this but it started getting complicated so I stopped)? Or the Comparison test(what should I compare it to?)?

Comment: Comparison or Limit comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{k^2}$. The Ratio Test won't work, the convergence of the terms to $0$ is too slow for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comparison: $ \displaystyle \left(\sin \frac 1 k \right)^2 < \left( \frac 1 k \right)^2$.

Comment: How did you derive that inequality?

Comment: For $x\in (0,\pi/2)$, define $g(x)=x-\sin x$. Then, we have $g'(x)=1-\cos x >0$ for every $x$ in that interval. That means that the function is strictly increasing, and $g(0)=0$, so we have $x-\sin x>0 \implies \sin x<x$. Note that $1/k < \pi/2$ for every $k\geq 1$.

Comment: @TanMath : Notice that $\sin'(0)=1$ but $\sin'x = \cos x<1$ for $0<x\le1$. The mean value theorem says $\Big( \sin x - \sin 0\Big)/\Big(x-0\Big) = \sin' c = \cos c < 1$ for some $c$ between $0$ and $x$.  Hence $\sin x \cdot \cos c = x$, so $\sin x < x$.  (This assumes $x>0$, since multiplying both sides by $x$ would otherwise require changing "$<$" to "$>$". That is a rigorous solution, but you should also know another approach: Think about what the graph of sine function looks like, with its slope of $1$ at $x=0$, and what the line $y=x$ looks like. That should tell you${}\,\ldots\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$that the curve lies below the line, so $\sin x<x$ whenever $x>0$.  Your understanding of the sine-in-radians function is incomplete if you haven't got that. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy but this is $sin(1/k)$, not $sin(x)$

Comment: So $x=1/k$.  When I say $\sin x<x$ whenever $x>0$, that's saying something about ALL positive numbers.  And $1/k$ is a positive number.  Whatever applies to ALL positive numbers applies to $1/k$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: TYPO: I should have written $\sin x = x\cos c$.  Then observe that $x\cos c < x\cdot 1$ since $\cos c<1$, etc. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy BTW, I think indicating $sin(x) < x$ is good for my purpose.. thanks for the answer...

Answer (score 3):

With *equivalents:*
$\sin^2\dfrac1k\sim_\infty \dfrac1{k^2}$.
The series $\displaystyle\sum\dfrac1{k^2}$ converges absolutely, hence $\displaystyle\sum\sin^2\dfrac1k$ converges absolutely.

I recall $f(x)\sim_\infty g(x)$, for two functions defined in a neighbourhood of $\infty$ roughly means
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$$
To take into account that $g(x)$ can be equal to $0$, there is a technical definition:
$$f(x)-g(x)=_{\infty}o\bigl(g(x)\bigr),$$
which is equivalent to the  previous definition in case $g(x)\neq 0$ in some neighbourhood of $\infty$.

Comment: I think you ought to say what $\sim_\infty$ means when posting something like this.  Is this the same as limit comparison? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Don't you think it's clear from emphasising the word ‘equivalent’?

Comment: No.  There are many equivalence relations. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: OK, I'll dot it. Buts as far as I know there is only one sense for the *noun* ‘equivalent’

Comment: There are certainly many senses of the word "equivalent". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I was speaking of the noun, not simply the word. ;o)

Comment: As either a noun or an adjective, there are many senses. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: For a nou, I don't see, that's all. But I'm very far from knowing all of maths…